# How to run shell script 100 times in parallel

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following for loop that process 100 with the customer ref and a Du Id

```
echo SCRIPT: $0

# TEST.sh arguments
# $1 = Order Ref
# $2 = DU ID
# $3 = Service Level.
# $4 = PostCode, Example EAST 4600 WEST 6900.
# $5 = Weight, to test PD_MAXI-C.

echo "Enter Customer Order Ref (e.g. 20001000)"
read P_CUST_ORDER_REF
echo "Enter DU Id (e.g. 20001000)"
read P_DU_ID


echo "-------------------LOGISTICAPOST------------------"

set -vx
for i in {1..100}
do
  echo "This should return PD_PRIVATPAKKER_E"
  ./1161-I-007-Consignor_Performance_Test.sh ${P_CUST_ORDER_REF} ${P_DU_ID} LOGISTICAPOST 4600 5000 &

  (( P_CUST_ORDER_REF++ ))
  (( P_DU_ID++ ))
done
```

I am trying to make it run 100 instances in parallel and processes them. However when I run this script I get back 1 reply. What should happen is that it process 100 orders and 100 records are put into the table. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: "I get back 1 reply" - what do you mean by "reply"? are you overwriting the same file again and again?

Comment: No I mean, in the putty terminal I get back 1 reply saying that it being processed. Ideally it should give back 100 "replies" and then when I view the web interface table it should contain 100 records.

Comment: You should try with a simpler command first, like "echo" so that people can reproduce your problem. You seem to be on the right track though.

Comment: try adding shell debugging above your loop, i.e. `set -vx`, `set +vx` later to turn it off. You'll see each block of code (the loop) and the values of variables as they are expanded. Also, why not move the assignments `(( ... ))` above the call to the script. What is setting values for the first use of $P_CUST_ORDER_DEF? Good luck.

Comment: I've updated my code which shows where $P_CUST_ORDER_REF is being set.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine -- given the pieces seen, it can be expected to work as-advertised. That said, a C-style for loop would be a bit more efficient (not generating the full list of numbers up-front and iterating over them, but just doing an increment and test): `for (( i=0; i<100; i++ )); do ...`

Comment: ...well, perfectly fine wrt re: this question; you should quote your variable expansions (`${P_CUST_ORDER_REF}` should be `"$P_CUST_ORDER_REF"`), and naming bash scripts ending in .sh is considered poor form (if they're libraries, they should be .bash to indicate that they don't run on POSIX sh; if they're executables, they shouldn't have extensions at all)... and to conform with convention, variables which aren't exported to the environment should have at least one lower-case letter (all-lower-case is typical); this stops them from conflicting with built-in and environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

I thought that [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) may be useful here. It allows to run command in parallel, like you wish. See [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) with lot of examples.